# spring <security:authorize not working with annotated controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a controller that have
`@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER')")`
and when I try to render some specific part of the page with `<security:authorize url="path-to-controller">` it gets passed even that logged in user does not have permission to access that controller.
In my security configuration I have added:
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)`

When the specific url is configured in security configuration, to forbid specific roles from accessing it, the security tag works, but is not working with annotations on controllers. It is possible to achieve same behavior with annotations?

Comment: No. That only works with the security configuration and URLs in there. It doesn't scan all the beans available in the context to pre-activly execute all the `@PreAuthorize` annotations. Which may or may not relate to a URL.

Comment: I pretty much thought so. Thanks!